# If - return is a huge bottleneck in my application

Tags: c#, performance

This is a snippet of code from my C# application:

```
public Player GetSquareCache(int x, int y)
{
    if (squaresCacheValid)
        return (Player)SquaresCache[x,y];
    else
        //generate square cache and retry...
}
```

`squareCacheValid` is a private bool and `SquaresCache` is private uint[,].

The problem was that the application is running extremely slow and any optimization just made it slower, so I ran a tracing session.

I figured that `GetSquareCache()` gets **94.41%** own time, and the if and return split that value mostly evenly (46% for if and 44.82% for return statement). Also the method is hit cca. 15,000 times in 30 seconds, in some tests going up to 20,000.

Before adding methods that call `GetSquareCache()`, program preformed pretty well but was using random value instead of actual `GetSquareCache()` calls.

**My questions are:** is it possible that these `if/return` statements used up so much CPU time? How is it possible that `if` statements `GetSquareCache()` is called in (which in total are hit the same number of times) have minimal own time? And is it possible to speed up the fundamental computing operation **if**?

**Edit:** Player is defined as

```
public enum Player
{
    None = 0,
    PL1 = 1,
    PL2 = 2,
    Both = 3
}
```

Comment: How big is the array SquaresCache[,]?

Comment: One thing to try, get rid of the multi-dimensional array.

Comment: There's nothing in an `if` statement and the retrieval of an element from an array that is going to slow your app down.  The issue is obviously that you're doing it so much but we can't help you with that because we have no context.

Comment: Why are you TypeCasting your return?.."return (Player)SquaresCache[x,y];".This looks like the culprit.   It will be helpful if you provide much more info about your array SquaresCache;

Comment: casting uint to Player? Do you have an explicit cast defined?

Comment: SquaresCache is constantly 14x14. I'll try to change it into a uint[][], to see if it helps. And as it stands now, it cannot be sped up, unless we change a lot of other code, which is on the way. And Player is just an enum.

Comment: are you sure that `squaresCacheValid` is `true`?

Comment: after generating the cache, it is set to true. Tracing also shows that generation method is hit only once, so it's definitely working as intended.

Comment: performance percentages don't say too much. What is meant with "own time"? More interesting: What is the time in milliseconds? if own time means all the time in the method than the time within splits about half to half to the 2 statements. Which does not state much about performance

Comment: "Own time" is time that call frame was on top of call stack, i.e. without calls to other functions (which is the same for this method). Being 94% of own time, means own time is 94% of total program execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach , under the assumption that most of the values in the square **hold no player**, and that the **square is very large** remember only location where there are players,

It should look something like this :

```
public class PlayerLocaiton
{
    Dictionary<Point, List<Player>> _playerLocation = new ...
    public void SetPlayer(int x, int y, Player p)
    {
      _playerLocation[new Point(x,y)].add(p); 
    }

    public Player GetSquareCache(int x, int y)
    {
      if (squaresCacheValid)
      {
           Player value;
           Point p = new Point(x,y);
           if(_playerLocation.TryGetValue(p, out value))
           {
                return value ;
           }

           return Player.None; 
      }
      else
        //generate square cache and retry...
   }
}
```

Comment: It is saved exactly as you proposed in first place. I thought caching them in a matrix would speed the process

Comment: calling point constructor twice instead of using TryGetValue shouldnt be in "performance critical" code. Also replacing an array with dictionary based on point value key in hope of improved performance sounds weird.

Comment: OH MY GOD, you're a genius! Got hit 3 million times in 40 seconds! Works like a charm! It got less than 9 seconds **total** time in those 40 seconds!

Comment: Also I used Tuple instead of custom Point class, and stored the constructed object in a variable, so it's probably just duplicated on stack

Comment: magic: we add insane overhead to original method and improve performance tenfold.

Comment: Somehow adding this increased processor usage to 25% (whole thread of a Intel i5), while old one barely got some processor time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is just the fact that method is called way too many times. And indeed, 34,637 ms it gets in last trace, over 34,122 hits it got is a little over 1ms per hit. In decompiled CIL code there are also some assignments to local variables not present in code in both if branches because it needs one `ret` statement. The algorithm itself is what needs to be modified, and such modifications were planned anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. replace return type of this method to int and remove the casting
   to Player
2. if cache is to be set once remove the if from this method so
       it is always true when the method is called
3. replace array with single
           dimension array and access it via unsafe fixed way

Comment: But there is still the issue of saving unneeded data of where there are no players, which is most of the board.

Comment: @user table is 14x14 or 176. What are you talking about really.

Comment: @Valentin Kuzub, Where do you see mentioned the size of the matrix?

Comment: @user comment from question starter: SquaresCache is constantly 14x14. I'll try to change it into a uint[][], to see if it helps. And as it stands now, it cannot be sped up, unless we change a lot of other code, which is on the way. And Player is just an enum. –  StarGate TABC 2 days ago